# Div and menu links show-hide onclick outside of div

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on website where I want to show-hide Div (RED COLOR DIV) on click.

1. when user click on word "HIDE" (inside navigation bar).. javascript function will hide all the menu links (not logo) and show RED DIV
2. now when RED DIV is visible and only LOGO link is visible, so when user clicks anywhere outside of RED DIV it should TOGGLE the javascript function and make RED DIV hidden and All menu links visible again

so far i have done this. I only need javascript code

```js
function aniToggle() {

    document.getElementById("hideshow").style.display = "block";

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("anivisib");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].classList.toggle("toggle-anivisib");
    }
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

#hideshow {

height: 500px;
z-index:2;
position: absolute;
left: 30%;
top: 0;
background-color: red; 
display: none;
}

.toggle-anivisib {
 visibility: hidden;


}
```

```html
<header>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#news">LOGO</a></li>

  <li><a class="active anivisib" href="#home" onclick="aniToggle()">HIDE</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news" class="anivisib">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" class="anivisib">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about" class="anivisib">About</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="hideshow" >
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
</div>
</header>

<main>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onclick="aniToggle()"`, I have passed an event to stop [Event Propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation) this event will not propagate to the `document.onclick` , add `document.onclick` which will detect click events on the document.

```js
function aniToggle(ev) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        document.getElementById("hideshow").style.display = "block";
        toggleElements('anivisib');
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        var divToHide = document.getElementById('hideshow');
        document.onclick = function(e){
            if(e.target.id !== 'hideshow' && !divToHide.contains(e.target)){
                //element clicked wasn't the div; hide the div
                if (divToHide.style.display == 'block') {
                    divToHide.style.display = 'none';
                    toggleElements('anivisib');
                }
            }
        };
    };

    function toggleElements(cls) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].classList.toggle("toggle-anivisib");
        }
    }
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

#hideshow {

height: 500px;
z-index:2;
position: absolute;
left: 30%;
top: 0;
background-color: red; 
display: none;
}

.toggle-anivisib {
 visibility: hidden;


}
```

```html
<header>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#news">LOGO</a></li>

  <li><a class="active anivisib" href="#home" onclick="aniToggle(event)">HIDE</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news" class="anivisib">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" class="anivisib">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about" class="anivisib">About</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="hideshow" >
<div>
<div>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>

<main>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
</main>
```

Comment: when i am clicking on red area it is closing ! please take a look. clicking inside anywhere red div should not close the div sir

Comment: try to click on text inside RED DIV. it is closing RED DIV which is wrong

Comment: thanks I think this will work. let me try it on my website and I will reply you

Comment: glad I could help.

Comment: @ArchiPatel please think of [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: only 1 problem I'm facing now. which is when i have <P> inside a child "div". and when user clicks on text it is closing RED DIV. i have updated html code and added 2 div. can you plz solve that issue ? that's what i need at last.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143059/discussion-between-archi-patel-and-julekgwa).

Answer (score -1):

assuming you have an `id="hide"` on hide button's `li` tag:

```
<li id="hide"><a href="#home" class="anivisib">HIDE</a></li>
```

you can use this jquery solution to achieve the behaviour that you want:

The `sample` name for mousedown event is to make sure only this event will get unbinded

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    // The function to toggle visibility of elements
    var aniToggle = function(){
        $('li').not(':first-child').toggle();
        $('div#hideshow').toggle();
    }

    // Clicking on hide li runs aniToggle function and set an event for document click
    $('li#hide').click(function(){
        aniToggle();

        $(document).on('mousedown.sample', function(e){
            if( 
                // If the click target is not #hideshow div
                !$(e.target).is('div#hideshow') && 

                // And also not its child elements
                $(e.target).parents('div#hideshow').length == 0
            ){

                // Run aniToggle function
                aniToggle();

                // Unbind the click element from document so it doesn't fire on each click
                $(document).off('mousedown.sample');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

#hideshow {

height: 500px;
z-index:2;
position: absolute;
left: 30%;
top: 0;
background-color: red; 
display: none;
}

.toggle-anivisib {
 visibility: hidden;


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#news">LOGO</a></li>

  <li id="hide"><a href="#home" class="anivisib">HIDE</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news" class="anivisib">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" class="anivisib">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about" class="anivisib">About</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="hideshow" >
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
</div>
</header>

<main>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
<p>hi hih ih ih ih ih i hi hi h ih ih ih i hi </p>
</main>
```

Comment: The question was not tagged with `jQuery`.

Comment: need a javascript only

Comment: I've edited my answer a little to behave exactly how you want. however it's still in jQuery.